# parsing wikipedia page content

Tags: html, json, parsing, python-3.x, wikipedia-api

I'm looking for a library to parse html pages, specifically wikipedia articles for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railgun, I want to extract the article's text and images (full scale or original image not the thumb).
Is there an html parser out there ?
I would prefer not to use the wikimedia api since I can't seem to figure out how to extract an article's text and the fullsize images with them.
Thanks and sorry for my english.

EDIT: I forgot to say that the ending result should be valid html

EDIT: I got the json string with this: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&pageid=218930&prop=text&format=json so now I need to parse the json.
I know that in javascript I can do something like this:
var pageHTML = JSON.parse("the json string").parse.text["*"];
Since I know a bit of html/javascript and python, how can I make that http request and parse the json in python 3 ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be able to get everything with the webapi,

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext

or you could download the whole wikipedia

https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Research:Data

Answer (score 2):

You can get the html from the api too, check the info on https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TextExtracts/pt, it's like this example: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&exchars=175&titles=hello%20world .

Depending on how many pages you'll need, you should consider using public dumps if the volume of pages is high.

Answer (score 0):

I made a [Node.js module](https://github.com/tomer8007/wikipedia-to-json) called wikipedia-to-json (written in javascript) that parses the HTML in wikipedia articles and gives you back structed JSON objects that describe the layout of the article in-order. (titles, paragraphs, images, lists, sub-titles...)

That might be useful if you just want to do a quick extractions of text and sections and understand how things look like.